# Require.js model collection fetch difficulty

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

Okay I'm going to do my best to explain this.

I am using require.js. I have a file named **ScheduleView.js** and it loads **Subject.js**.

**Subject.js**

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'underscore',
    'backbone',
    'libs/myFunctions/schedule/collections/SubjectList'
], function($, _, Backbone, SubjectList){
    var Subject = Backbone.Model.extend({
        initialize: function(){
            subjectList = new SubjectList;
            subjectList.fetch({
                success: function(){
                    console.log('yay! fetched');
                }
            })

...

return Subject;
```

The **Subject** model is used ALOT. And I can't make it fetch the data every time. That's just a waste of performance. It's also too much of a hassle to initialize **Subject** once in the **ScheduleView** and pass on the variable;

Are there other alternatives of doing this?

Hope you understand the problem.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Aha! Inside 'libs/myFunctions/schedule/collections/SubjectList' i simply wrote:

```
var subjectList = new Subject
return subjectList
```

That way I could simple include the link every time I needed it with only having it fetched the information once.